# Navigate to "coded PhoneApplicationPage"

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm a bit confused right now. How can I navigate to a **PhoneApplicationPage** that has **no *.xaml** bound to it. I don't even know what I should search after to find a solution. Maybe braintilt.

Comment: My 0.02$: there be dragons here. The built-in navigation framework isn't built for pages without XAML. You're about to enter a world of pain. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

try this : 
`Me.NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri("PhoneApplicationPage",Urikind.Relative))`

But how is it possible not to have .xaml ?

Comment: `private class FacebookConnectPage : PhoneApplicationPage`  just created a own page from code.

Comment: I think this will not work I even have the Page object initialized and feeded with information that it require.

Comment: A private class won't be available to the framework. It's only available to the class it's nested in. The framework is outside that context.